# How to create CorDapp jar file without redeploying nodes?

Tags: corda

We are using Corda Version 4 for our application.

We understand that the command **gradlew.bat deployNodes** creates following jars -

1. CorDapp (contracts, states, flows)
2. Corda platform
3. Dependencies

When any change is made in the contract/states/flows code, we had to run the command **gradlew.bat deployNodes** each time. Due to this the "Corda platform" and "Dependencies" jars always get recreated and consequently increases development time.

Does Corda platform provides alternative way to **Only** create "CorDapp" jar file and not the remaining ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use following cmd to generate only jar files**

```
./gradlew build
```

**this will generate jar files in you build/lib folder**